# Why daemon's output can just goto /tmp dir?

Tags: python, daemon, python-daemon

the supper class I use is http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/, my code is below:

```
import os
import sys, time
from daemon import Daemon
class MyDaemon(Daemon):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            cmd='cat test.txt > output.txt'
            os.system(cmd)
            time.sleep(6000)
if __name__ == "__main__":     
    daemon = MyDaemon('/tmp/DebugDaemon.pid')
    daemon.start()
```

If I run DebugDaemon.py, the /tmp/DebugDaemon.pid can be created.

However, ouput.txt file can not be created, why?

If I call it directly (ie: No using the daemon code) work fine.

Comment: You're not actually running anything there.  All you're doing is setting a variable named cmd, and then sleeping.

Comment: cmd is a local variable, you have to call some function to do anything and maybe set cmd to self.cmd so your class knows about cmd.

Comment: Does your call to the `MyDaemon` constructor work? Or did you omit the constructor code?

Answer (score 1):

`cmd` is a local variable. Your assignment to it doesn't actually do anything, since no code uses it.

The `subprocess` module allows you to call other programs from within Python. I don't know how it interacts with daemons though.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when typing this qus

Answer (score 1):

`Daemon` appears to [`chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-parameters) to `/`. I bet your process doesn't have write permissions for `/`.

Your daemon needs to `chdir()` to the directory where `test.txt` resides (and for which the process has write permissions). Alternatively, use full paths everywhere:

```
cmd = 'cat /tmp/test.txt > /tmp/output.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

the

```
cat test.txt > output.txt
```

is executed in / because the super class does

```
# decouple from parent environment
os.chdir("/")
```

the pid-file can be written, because everybody can write to /tmp - / is not writable for everybody.